# Struggling to understand Twisted in general and pb in particular

Tags: python, twisted, perspective-broker

Could someone explain the difference between the following please. I am really struggling to grasp Deferred concept, I thought I had it as I have been doing examples all day. But I think i must be code blind. I'm sure its really simple.

This works.

```
from twisted.spread import pb
from twisted.internet import reactor
from twisted.python import util


if __name__ == '__main__':

    def print_result(result):
        print result

    def add_numbers(obj, a, b):
        obj.callRemote("add_numbers", a, b)



    factory = pb.PBClientFactory()
    reactor.connectTCP("localhost", 8789, factory)
    d = factory.getRootObject()
    d.addCallback(lambda object: object.callRemote("add_numbers", 1, 2))
    d.addErrback(lambda reason: 'error: '+str(reason.value))
    d.addCallback(print_result)
    d.addErrback(lambda reason: 'error: '+str(reason.value))
    d.addCallback(lambda _: reactor.stop())
    d = factory.getRootObject()

    reactor.run()
```

and this doesnt

```
from twisted.spread import pb
from twisted.internet import reactor
from twisted.python import util


if __name__ == '__main__':

    def print_result(result):
        print result

    def add_numbers(obj, a, b):
        obj.callRemote("add_numbers", a, b)



    factory = pb.PBClientFactory()
    reactor.connectTCP("localhost", 8789, factory)
    d = factory.getRootObject()
    d.addCallback(add_numbers, 1, 2)
    d.addErrback(lambda reason: 'error: '+str(reason.value))
    d.addCallback(print_result)
    d.addErrback(lambda reason: 'error: '+str(reason.value))
    d.addCallback(lambda _: reactor.stop())
    d = factory.getRootObject()

    reactor.run()
```

I cant for the life of me work out why, it crashes with this error:

```
Unhandled error in Deferred:
Unhandled Error
Traceback (most recent call last):
Failure: twisted.spread.pb.PBConnectionLost: [Failure instance: Traceback (failure  with no frames): <class 'twisted.internet.error.ConnectionLost'>: Connection to the other side was lost in a non-clean fashion: Connection lost.
]
```

Server side code is

```
from twisted.spread import pb
from twisted.internet import reactor

class Echoer(pb.Root):
    def remote_echo(self, st):
        print 'echoing:', st
        return st

    def remote_add_numbers(self, a, b):
        print 'adding:', a, b
        c = a + b
        return c

if __name__ == '__main__':
    reactor.listenTCP(8789, pb.PBServerFactory(Echoer()))
    reactor.run()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference between your working and broken examples is that the `lambda` expression implicitly returns its result.  Its result is a `Deferred`, which means that the next callback in the chain will wait to execute until its result is available.

If you change the definition of `add_numbers` to return the result of `callRemote`, like so:

```
def add_numbers(obj, a, b):
    return obj.callRemote("add_numbers", a, b)
```

Then your broken example will start working again.

Comment: Ahhhh, that seems clearer now, I am a little confused as to why it gave me that error though. Why would that make me lose the connection?

Comment: It loses the connection because since returning immediately is "successful", it proceeds immediately to the next callback, which calls `reactor.stop()`.  The first thing that stopping the reactor does is drop all connections.